Issue with IIS Hosting: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN when Reloading
I have a project hosted on IIS that works fine most of the time. Sometimes reloading the page results in the error:
"This site can't be reached. Check if there is a typo in esuport.mm.local. If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN."
Interestingly, if I open another page (e.g., Google) and access the same URL, it works fine. The problem occurs temporarily and usually resolves itself after some time, but I need a more permanent fix.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this problem? Could this be related to DNS caching or IIS settings?

If the esuport.mm.local is the actual address you're using, I'd assume this is a local intranet site?
On the computer you're getting this issue, have you checked the DNS servers that it is using? Is it only using local DNS servers, eg those that locally have the esuport.mm.local DNS records, or does it also have public DNS servers?
For instance, check you don't have DNS servers listed as :
192.168.0.5  (eg local network)
8.8.8.8  (using Google's DNS)
Since any time your machine happened to pick the Google DNS to resolve the record, it would give that NXDOMAIN response since it would report that there is no such domain... accurately, since there's no such domain on the internet, and Google doesn't know about your local network.

I suspect the issue might be related to the DNS configuration or a possible misconfiguration in the IIS server. To identify the root cause, I plan to use the IP address of the local server directly (e.g., http://192.168.5.20) instead of the domain name (esupport.mm.local).
This approach will help determine whether the problem lies with the DNS resolution or if it’s a binding/misconfiguration issue in IIS. If accessing the application via the IP works correctly, then the problem is likely with the DNS.

@JurgesLika: A misconfiguration with the IIS server will not cause the endpoint to not resolve a name.

I understand the problem better now. Thanks guys

As @Keith Langmead was mentioning, it's a DNS issue on the machine where the browser is running, not in the IIS web server machine. Check the DNS client / resolver library configuration. Make a network capture on port 53,UDP (and maybe TCP) with  Wireshark or similar.
